# Is there a difference in handling event using KonvaJS and KineticJS?

Tags: kineticjs, konvajs

Is there a difference between [KonvaJS](http://konvajs.github.io/) and KineticJS regarding handling events?
Using the same code, the events like `mouseover` and other are only working using KineticJS.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Any code example?
This demo works fine: http://konvajs.github.io/docs/events/Binding_Events.html

Comment: OK, thanks for the response. I'm trying to extract some things. But its not very special, only inside a larger project. Using stage, layer ... maybe it takes a little bit

Answer (score 0):

I'm just converting KineticJS to KonvaJs.
The mouseover behavior work the same in my code.

What work   different in stage  is movement behavior.
My code  has used

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({

                draggable: true,
                dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
}
```

in KineticJS pos has been calculated movement  only for current move ex:

```
1. move mause 10 to right => pos = {10,0}
2. move mause 10 to up => pos = {0,10}
3. move mause 10 to up => pos = {0,10}
```

In konvajs pos has calculated as sum of all stage movement

```
1. move mause 10 to right => pos = {10,0}
2. move mause 10 to up => pos = {10,10}
3. move mause 10 to up => pos = {10,20}
```